# I can not Ola Hallengren database backup script to Data Domain make works

Tags: backup, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

Ola Hallengren has a nice SQL Maintenance scripts that I installed to our dev SQL server. The backup script works very well to a local drive, however it does not work to Data Domain. At all.

Here is the script:

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
 @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
 @BackupType = 'FULL',
 @CheckSum = 'Y',
 @BackupSoftware = 'DATA_DOMAIN_BOOST',
 @DataDomainBoostHost = 'ourdatadomainhost',
 @DataDomainBoostUser = 'ouruser',
 @DataDomainBoostDevicePath = '/ourdevicepath',
 @DataDomainBoostLockboxPath = 'C:\Program Files\DPSAPPS\common\lockbox',
 @CleanupTime = 240
```

Here is the output (truncated):

> Date and time: 2019-04-16 14:52:39 Command: DECLARE @ReturnCode int
>   EXECUTE @ReturnCode = [master].dbo.emc_run_backup ' -c DEVSQLSERVER -l
>   full -y +10d -k -S 1 -a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_HOST=ourdatadomainhost" -a
>   "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_USER=ouruser" -a
>   "NSR_DFA_SI_DEVICE_PATH=/ourdevicepath" -a
>   "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_LOCKBOX_PATH=C:\Program Files\DPSAPPS\common\lockbox"
>   -a "NSR_SKIP_NON_BACKUPABLE_STATE_DB=TRUE" "MSSQL:1_DB"' IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR('Error performing Data Domain Boost
>   backup.', 16, 1)
>
> Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Line 1 An error occurred in the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65536. The
>   server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be
>   trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query
>   again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust
>   issues. For more information about this error:
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ddbmasqlclrlib, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c0f9ccf99c6c0e66' or one of its dependencies. An error
>   relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)

I tried many things, including

1. `ALTER DATABASE 1_DB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON`
2. Change `1_DB owner` to `sa`
3. Running MS SQL Server Management Studio in administrator mode

I can not figure out what I can do more to solve this problem.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you try executing the CLR stored procedure outside of DatabaseBackup?

EXECUTE [master].dbo.emc_run_backup ' -c DEVSQLSERVER -l full -y +10d -k -S 1 -a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_HOST=ourdatadomainhost" -a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_USER=ouruser" -a "NSR_DFA_SI_DEVICE_PATH=/ourdevicepath" -a "NSR_DFA_SI_DD_LOCKBOX_PATH=C:\Program Files\DPSAPPS\common\lockbox" -a "NSR_SKIP_NON_BACKUPABLE_STATE_DB=TRUE" "MSSQL:1_DB"'

Comment: I have tried, but I have got a same error message.   Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65536. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ddbmasqlclrlib, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken...

Comment: Have you tried asking Dell EMC support?